# Restarting a Program with a Loop

Tags: java, loops

I've looked through posts and can't seem to find an answer pertaining to my problem.

I'm a beginner in java and have to make a program in which a user enters a password and the program I write checks to make sure it meets the requirements:

- At least 8 characters
- Contains an uppercase and lowercase character
- Contains a special character

After it does so it is supposed to ask the user if they want to enter another one. Here is my code:

```
public class Password
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "!@#$%^&*()~`-=_+[]{}|:\";',./<>?";
      int MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      String password;
      char answer;
      boolean continueRun = true;


      while(continueRun)
      {
         password = "";
         System.out.print("Enter a password: ");
         password = scan.nextLine();

         boolean hasUppercase = !password.equals(password.toLowerCase());
         boolean hasLowercase = !password.equals(password.toUpperCase());
         boolean hasSpecial   = !password.matches("[A-Za-z0-9 ]*");
         boolean atLeast8   = password.length() >= 8;
         if(!hasUppercase || !hasLowercase || !atLeast8 || !hasSpecial)
         {
           System.out.println("Entered password is:\t" + password);
           System.out.println("Verdict:\tInvalid");
         }
         else
         {
           System.out.println("Entered password:\t" + password);
           System.out.println("Verdict:\t\tValid");
         }
         System.out.print("Enter another password? Y/N: ");
           answer = scan.next().charAt(0);
           if (answer != 'Y')
           {
           continueRun = false;
           }
     }
   }
}
```

I know it's probably not the most efficient or clean but it gets things done. My only problem is whenever the user decides to continue the output is this:

```
Enter another password? Y/N: Y
Enter a password: Entered password is:  
Verdict:    Invalid
Enter another password? Y/N:
```

How do I make it repeat like how it does at the initial start of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `Scanner` inside the loop like this

```
while(continueRun)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...
```

So that the program will ask the user for the new password again.